# How to fix "undefined reference" compiler error

Tags: c++, oop

find a bug in following code :

```
class A
{
   public:
    static int i;
    void print()
    {
      cout<< i << endl ;
    }
 };

 int main()
 {
    A a;
    a.print();
  }
```

I run above code, and I am getting **"undefined reference to `A::i'"** . Why I am getting this error ?

Answer (score 12):

Since `A::i` is a `static` member, it has to be [defined outside of the class](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr038.htm):

```
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    static int i;  // A::i is declared here.

    void print()
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
};

int A::i = 42;     // A::i is defined here.
```

Answer (score 7):

The `static int i` in the `class A` is just a *declaration*, you need to *define* it outside the class by adding a statement `int A::i = 0;`